# Which one is the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

Notice that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ are both groups. I want to know which of the case is true:

1) $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$

2) $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \{n\} \subset \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I saw 1) being written in a textbook. I am confused since from the definition of a subgroup, an element of a subgroup is defined from an element of a subgroup.

Also, given the above question, if 2) is true and 1) is not well defined, how should I rewrite
$$(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})/k\mathbb{Z} \quad ?$$

Comment: For 1), you can say that $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ contains a *copy* of $\mathbb{Z}$: the elements $\{(n,0): n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. But it also contains the copy $\{(0,n): n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, or the copy $\{(n,n): n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, or even $\{(n,2n): n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. So you need to specify which copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ (you need to specify an embedding $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$), and only then you can talk about the quotient $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})/k\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For 2), this is only true if $n=0$. Otherwise $(0,n)+(0,n)=(0,2n)\not \in \mathbb{Z}\oplus \{n\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that (1) doesn't literally make sense because an integer is not a pair of integers. The author probably means either that $\Bbb Z\oplus\{0\}$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$ or that $\Bbb Z$ is *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$ (as there are many such subgroups, e.g. $\{(3x,4x)\mid x\in\Bbb Z\}$). Often isomoprhisms are treated notationally like equalities, and it's left to the reader to figure out the correct interpretation of a statement.

Statement (2) is true if we interpret $\subset$ as "is a subset of", but this subset is not a subgroup unless $n=0$, since $n+n\ne n$.

Finally, as Alvaro said in a comment, the quotient $(\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z)/k\Bbb Z$ isn't meaningful until we choose a specific subgroup to quotient by. So e.g. $(\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z)/k(\Bbb Z\oplus\{0\})$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

1 is not well defined. Rather, there is an embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ inside the direct sum. I use product notation, but it's the same as the direct sum. This corresponds to $\mathbb{Z} \times <0>$. 
2 is not a subgroup of the direct sum, unless $n$ is $0$. What I believe you meant to write is $\mathbb{Z} \times <n>$ where $<n>$ is used to denote the set generated by the integer $n$. 
When writing the quotient, it really depends on what you are asking.  For example you could quotient $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ with $<n> \times <n>$